# Return the matches from one method to another

Tags: java, regex

I'm an absolute Java beginner. I've searched on the forums, but couldn't find an answer to this question.

I have two classes, one which browses through an arraylist of sentences. I only attach the for-each loop as seen below.
"Matching" is the instance of the other class (containing the pattern/matcher code)
matchEndings is the method, attached below.

```
for (String sentence: sentences) {
    String match = matching.matchEndings(sentence);
    if (match.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(match);
    }
}
```

This is the method.

```
public String matchEndings(String s){
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(aa|ee)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

return m.group();
    
}
```

My question is, how do I return the matched sentences, containing aa / ee endings, to the first class, and have it printed there? The code is compiled, but when I run I get

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: So you want to print out all of the lines that end with aa or ee?

Comment: Yes, that's about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Matcher.group()` only returns if there is a match already. You need to do something like this:-

```
if (m.matches()) {
    return m.group();
} else {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! My only problem now is that it only finds the first occurence in "sentence". If the string is "Hee Aaa Oaa" followed by a new line character, it only returns "Hee". I know while (m.find()) would work if I wanted to print the result, but not now, when I intend to return it.

The arraylist "sentence" is filled up with scanner, from a textfile.

   Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
   while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    sentences.add(in.nextLine());
   }

Don't know how to proceed. Perhaps you could help me out! Thanks in advance guys

Comment: is your purpose to return all words that end with ee or aa in a string?

Comment: Yes! Thats what I intend to do.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like overkill to use RegEx when all you need is a simple `endsWith(String)`:

```
public void print(final List<String> sentences, final String... endings){
    for(final String sentence : sentences){
        for(final String ending : endings){
            if(sentence.endsWith(ending)){
                System.out.println(sentence);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method above will loop through a `List<String>` of sentences and print out all of the sentences that end with one of the elements in `endings`. For usage, you could try:

```
print(sentences, "aa", "ee");
```

Where `sentences` is your `ArrayList<String>` of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) or [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) methods must precede the `group` method. Since `matches` attempts to match the entire region against the pattern, it is more appropriate here

```
public String matchEndings(String s){
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(aa|ee)$");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.matches) {
   return m.group();
} else {
   return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class PotenssienSumma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        ArrayList<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>(10);
        sentences.add("aa");
        sentences.add("1324");
        for (String sentence: sentences) {
            String match = Matching.matchEndings(sentence);
            if (match.length() > 0) {
                 System.out.println(match);
            }
        }
    }
}   
class Matching{         
    public  static String matchEndings(String s){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(aa|ee)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            return m.group();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't construct Pattern in the method. That is expensive. Put the pattern object into a static final variable.
- The correct use for patterns is the following:

  ```
  while(matcher.find()) {
      sysout(matcher.group());
  }
  ```

This will print all matches, if you want just one match, replace the `while` with `if`.

- I don't know if this is intentional but your regex doesn't match `ee|aa` to end of the string. It matches `ee` or `aa` anywhere in the string along with any characters preceeding it. For instance for string `Fox preens in front of a vixen` your regex returns string `Fox pree`. Don't know if that's intended.

Here's a class that takes a list or a collection of strings as an argument and then lazily finds all words that end in `aa` or `ee`. It has a `main` method you can run to test.

```
    public class Endings implements Iterable<String> {
        private final Iterable<String> strings;
        private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\s)\\S*(aa|ee)(?=\\s|$)");

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Endings endings = new Endings(Arrays.asList("This testaabb testee testaa", "Test2aa Test3ee ", "no match"));
            for(String word : endings) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }

        public Endings(Iterable<String> strings) {
            this.strings = strings;
        }

        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String>() {
            private Iterator<String> iter = strings.iterator();
            private Matcher m;
            private String result;
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (result == null) {
                    if (m == null) {
                        if (iter.hasNext()) {
                            m = pat.matcher(iter.next());
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (m.find()) {
                        result = m.group();
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        m = null;
                        return hasNext();
                    }
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public String next() {
                if (result != null) {
                    String ret = result;
                    result = null;
                    return ret;
                } else {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
            }

            public void remove() {

            }
            };
    }

}
```